# MTU for WebServices

Tags: .net, web-services, networking, mtu

We have an ERP application which has all clients connect using WebService.  My network engineer tells me that the MTU of the webservice is too small and we would like to increase it to improve performance.  As far as I can tell there is no config section for MTU for dotnet web services.  Any ideas on where we could configure this?

Answer (score 1):

A web service doesn't have an MTU - it's controlled by the server OS, in this case Windows.

One of the best tools for tweaking MTU and other TCP settings is [SG TCP optimizer](http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.   I downloaded the tool and ran it and it gave me the same result as running ping manually....but the GUI tool is slick and allows me to test easily.

I will use it in future.